# fetch data from tableAdapter

Tags: c#, tableadapter, sql-server-2012-localdb

Using `Visual Studio 2012`

I have a sql database with a table(name of table: gTable). I have "gTabletableAdapter". I have wrote some query in gTabletableAdapter and now I can use them from Form1.cs like below.

```
greetingTableTableAdapter.SelectQuery(Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text));
```

this query returns an object: `object` .I want to use selected rows. How can I do that.
I don't want to use `sqlConnection`. I want to use the object which my tableAdapter returned.
I have searched a lot and found nothing. 
thanks.

Comment: If that returns a result set, as opposed to a scalar value, the "object" should be a strongly typed DataTable. Did you debug and inspect the returned object to see its properties?

Comment: when I use `object o=greetingTableTableAdapter.selectSingleValueQuery(textBox13.Text);
                richTextBox1.Text= o.ToString();` it ruturns me the id of firstSelected row. I don't know what is `object' and how I can use it :'(

Comment: Sounds like it is returning a scalar value and not a result set. What is the sql statement of the SelectQuery?

Comment: the code in `selectQuery` is:
`SELECT * FROM gTable WHERE question LIKE @q`

Comment: Please show the code for the SelectQuery method.

Comment: I have defined this function in tableAdapter and I had wrote the code in comment number 4!

Comment: "selectSingleValueQuery" is not the same as selectQuery. The former implies a scalar value is returned. We can't see enough of your code to know what you are trying to do, you are getting mixed up with what you want to call.

Comment: @Crowcoder : Oh. Yes . You are right.
`selectSingleValueQuery` means `SelectQuery`

Comment: It's simple. I have defined some queries in tableAdapter environment and now I want to use them in my main form. I want to fetch some info from my table and use them. how can I fetch data from my table using tableAdapter queries???

Comment: You must use the correct query for the data you want. The one you are using returns a single id value but you are expecting a result set of rows. I can't specifically tell you what to do because I can't see your project but you must use or create a query that returns the rows you want.